# Enmascarado de Email con jsp

Tags: jsp, mail

Buen día, actualmente tengo un `jsp` que es llamado desde `js` para hacer el envío de correo, quiero ver si es posible omitir o enmascarar el correo de `From` y que solo se muestre el `FromName`, dejo el código de como lo tengo:

```
package com.journaldev.mail;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class EmailUtil {

    /**
     * Utility method to send simple HTML email
     * @param session
     * @param toEmail
     * @param subject
     * @param body
     */
    public static void sendEmail(Session session, String toEmail, String subject, String body){
        try
        {
          MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
          //set message headers
          msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
          msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
          msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");

          msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no_reply@example.com", "NoReply-JD"));

          msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse("no_reply@example.com", false));

          msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");

          msg.setText(body, "UTF-8");

          msg.setSentDate(new Date());

          msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));
          System.out.println("Message is ready");
          Transport.send(msg);  

          System.out.println("EMail Sent Successfully!!");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que el destinatario solo vea `"NoReply-JD"`(que si pone el cursor sobre el `"NoReply-JD"` si se vea la dirección como tal `"no_reply@example.com"` )

he intentado mandar el `From` vacío o en lugar de poner un correo, poner un texto, pero en todos los casos marca error de valor no admitido

de antemano muchas gracias por su tiempo

Saludos.

Comment: Si hablas de poner un enlace en un HTML que al hacer click abra el cliente de correo para enviar un mensaje, reberías poner en la URL el esquema `mailto:`. Si hablas de poner un remitente en una cabecera de un correo, puedes asignarle la cadena `"NoReply-JD" <no_reply@example.com>` tal cual lo he escrito (el nombre entre comillas, el email entre ángulos). La mayoría de clientes de correo electrónico mostrarán sólo el nombre.

Comment: por lo que estaba viendo con `java 1.6`  funcionaba mandarle el `From` vacío y quedaba la estructura que yo quiero hacer: `"NoReply-JD"` (sin el email entre los ángulos) pero como ahora estoy usando `java 1.8` (no hay posibilidad de usar `1.6`) `java 1.8` no permite dejar el `from` vacío